# How can I convert the stripe session unit_amount to actual product_price.I am using AED

Tags: reactjs, node.js, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway with AED currency, in that my actual product_price is 100.00 AED, and in the stripe payment screen it is showing the same amount, but when I log the session details, the unit_amount is showing as 10000.

return {
price_data: {
currency: "aed",
product_data: {
name: product.product_name,
// images: [productImagePath],
metadata: {
address: JSON.stringify(address)
},
},
unit_amount: parseInt(product.product_price) * 100,
},
quantity: parseInt(product.product_qty),

```
    };
  }
);
console.log("Name:", lineItems);
```

this is my code and I have mentioned the unit_amount field, when I log lineItems I want to get the unit_amount as 100.00, but it is coming as 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe API uses the smallest unit of a currency to specify `amount`, e.g. cents for USD. Therefore, to specify an amount of $100 in Stripe API you need to specify `amount: 10000`, i.e. 10000 cents. You can read more here: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal

Comment: (The reason for this is to avoid floating-point math with decimals. Computers aren't great at it, so rounding can cause problems.)